# What does "accept sacrificial food" mean?

Tags: tractate-chagiga

[Chagigah 22a](https://www.sefaria.org/Chagigah.22a.13?lang=bi&lang2=en) discusses "accepting *terumah*" vs "accepting *kodesh*" from an unlearned person (*am ha'aretz*).

I understand what "accepting *terumah*" means: a farmer must give 1-2% of his produce to a Kohen and the question is whether a *kohen* who is a *chaver* can accept it.

What does "accepting *kodesh*" mean? I thought that *kodesh* is a part of (some) *korbanot* that the owner may consume. This means that the *am ha'aretz* brings his *living* animal to *beis ha'mikdash* where the *kohanim* bring the *korban* and give the parts that the owner will eat back to him. Now the *am ha'aretz* is in possession of *kodesh* meat.

Why would the *am ha'aretz* give it over to a *chaver*?
And, critically, why would he feel excluded from the sacrificial service if the *chaver* does not accept it?!

Or maybe they are talking about [*mincha*](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.2.3)?